# Error regarding crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

sometime i am getting a error when trying to generate report through crystal report and c#. but this error not occured everytime rather sometime it occured. please tell me anyone why this error occur and how to fix it.

### the error is

```
Error Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at EOD_Schedular.frmMain.GenerateReport(Boolean ViewOnly)
   at EOD_Schedular.frmMain.Generate(Boolean ViewOnly)


Method Name: GenerateReport
Line: 0
Column: 0
Sql: Not Found
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [google search for the error](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=&q=%22Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine%22). There are a lot of references. Most seem to be DLL version issues.